# What can TensorBoard do with TensorFlow that it cannot do with PyTorch?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, tensorboard

I've seen PyTorch's documentation on it's integration with TensorBoard namely `torch.utils.tensorboard` and I am wondering if it is lacking any features that would warrant learning TensorFlow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at all, as tensorboard is not learning anything. it just a logger that logs hyperparameter, losses